# error in writing data into file in python 

Tags: python, file-io

```
 a='aa'
>>> f=open("key.txt","w")


>>> s=str(a)
>>> f.write(s)
```

and still the key.txt file remains blank .. why?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use

```
f.flush()
```

to flush the write to disk. Or, if you are done using `f`, you could use

```
f.close()
```

to flush and close the file.

Answer (score 2):

This issue can be avoided completely by making use of **[the with statement](http://docs.python.org/whatsnew/2.5.html#pep-343-the-with-statement)**:

```
with open("key.txt","w") as f:
    s=str(a)
    f.write(s)
```

The file will be automatically closed when the block completes. Using **[the with statement](http://docs.python.org/whatsnew/2.5.html#pep-343-the-with-statement)** you need not worry about this sort of bug creeping into your code.